# Ubuntu 18.04: Customized list of GNOME Shell favorite apps not applied to new users

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I'm trying to customize the list of GNOME Shell favorite apps that **all new users** will get by default in their dash in Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Based on instructions from the GNOME System Administration Guide, I created a [profile](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-profiles.html.en) and a [keyfile](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-keyfiles.html.en) to customize the favorite-apps key of GNOME Shell in a global system database.

```
sudo su
# Create profile "user"
cat>/etc/dconf/profile/user<<"eof"
user-db:user
system-db:local
eof
# Create keyfile for system database "local"
mkdir /etc/dconf/db/local.d
cat >/etc/dconf/db/local.d/01-favorite-apps<<"eof"
[org/gnome/shell]
favorite-apps=['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'emacs25.desktop']
eof

dconf update
exit
```

The problem is that when I create a new user and this user then logs in for the first time, a new user database seems to be created automatically in $HOME/.config/dconf/user **which has Ubuntu's default settings for the favorite-apps key**. My global defaults from the system database /etc/dconf/db/local are ignored.

When launching dconf-editor as the new user after initial login, the favorite-apps key shows up as modified, but with Ubuntu's default list (Ubiquity,Nautilus etc.):

[image: Screenshot of dconf-editor]

I should add that the unexpected content of $HOME/.config/dconf/user does not come from /etc/skel. That directory only has a .profile, .bashrc, .bash_logout and examples.desktop - nothing GNOME related in there.

Only when the user (or an admin) **manually deletes the $HOME/.config/dconf/user file**, the global defaults from /etc/dconf/db/local will be applied the next time the user logs in.

What can I do to prevent this manual step and get the desired favorite apps right from start?